# Docker - Restrictions regarding naming container

Tags: docker

I have questions regarding restrictions about naming containers.
I search online and saw different issue and answers.

1. what is the maximum characters number in naming container?
2. which special characters are not allowed in docker container name? (e.g. '*', '$', ',', '_' ...)

Comment: I see  https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3138 but better check the code, I look for it

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The characters allowed to represent a container name is represented by the regex : 
[src code](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/be97c66708c24727836a22247319ff2943d91a03/daemon/names/names.go)

```
// RestrictedNameChars collects the characters allowed to represent a name, normally used to validate container and volume names.
const RestrictedNameChars = `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]`
```

see [#3138](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3138)

And only the images name has a limited size of 30 chars.

Comment: That regex also means that the container name can't be one letter long.

Comment: an error is reported when a container image name has capital letters

Comment: @LeoY What do you mean?

Comment: @MrR, when you try to tag container image (or build) and you use capital letters, you will get an error from daemon that will look smth like:
`Error parsing reference: "Image:Label" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase`

Comment: @LeoY That's tagging (naming) an _image_ ; this question and answer are about naming _containers_. The rules are different.

Comment: The 30 character image name limit has been increased to 255 for `namespace/repository`: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10392, see also: https://success.docker.com/article/dtr-max-length-repo-name

Answer (score 8):

Container names must start with an alphanumeric character and can then use `_` `.` or `-` in addition to alphanumeric. `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+`

I'm not sure there is a hard limit set for the length of a container name.  You might run into some HTTP URL limits at some point as the name ends up in the path for a number of API calls.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer to question 1

To be able to communicate between containers by using container names, the name length must be **maximum 63 characters**.

*Otherwise the DNS lookup will **fail silently***.

Fail silently means that in Ubuntu, there is no trace of any errors anywhere. At least not in:

- `stdout`
- `tail -f /var/log/syslog`
- `journalctl -xefu docker.service`
- `docker log your_container_name_or_id`

`"debug": true` was in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

More info, discussion and hopefully a warning in a future:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27763
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/46928

#### Answer to question 2

The name must comply with the regex here:

https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/daemon/names/names.go#L6

Which today is:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]
```

meaning allowed characters are:

- numbers `0-9`
- lowercase letters `a-z`
- uppercase letters `A-Z`
- underscore `_`
- point `.`
- hyphen `-`

Must begin with numbers or letters. Minimum length of 2 characters.